# Code coloring in preformatted text

Tags: discussion

When adding pre-formatted text in the Markdown editor on main, the text doesn't get coloured even when I explicitly tell it that it is PHP code like this example:

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->

    public function someFunction(){
        $variable = Mage::getModel('router/somemodel');
    }
```

Is this a bug? Or is code colouring only available on select SE websites?

I'm not sure what to tag this post with since it's probably by design and not a bug. So I tagged it with [discussion](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC this is a limitation when the site is a BETA.

Comment: I sure hope so!

Comment: I would definitely like to see code colouring even in Beta. I feel it devalues the site somewhat when you have a block of code that's borderline unreadable.

Comment: Me too, I vote for code coloring(for PHP/HTML, XML, JS & SQL) to be enabled asap.